# How to determine which node was clicked. Silverlight treeview

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How to determine on over which node click was performed?
Treeview from silverlight toolkit.

In MouseRightButtonUp i need to get node:

private void treeView_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MouseButtonEventArgs` has an `OriginalSource` property which indicates the actual `UIElement` that generated the event.

In order to discover which Node that element belongs to you will need to traverse the visual tree to discover it.  I use this extension method to assist with that:-

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Ancestors(this DependencyObject root)
    {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
    }
```

Then in the `MouseRightButtonUp` event you can use this code to find the item:-

```
 TreeViewItem node = ((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource)
                        .Ancestors()
                        .OfType<TreeViewItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is the name "Ancestors" in your second piece of code?

Comment: @Telaclavo: Well spotted it was missing from the usage example where is should have been.  Edited.